# Why do node setups shift when I select their objects?

Tags: node-editor

Thoughts?

I thought it was related to object origin, but snapping origins to world center did nothing.
Also I Applied all transformations.  Nothing.

I'm stumped.

[image: shifting nodes]

Comment: Although not very easy to see just like a 3D scene, a node tree also has coordinate space with an origin. If your node trees ended up being constructed far away from the origin the node editor appears to jump around when in fact it is the nodes that are misplaced.